# Spotify Android SDK - Android Auth 1.0. How to build

Tags: android, spotify, android-developer-api

I am new to Android programming.  I am trying to integrate the Spotify SDK into an Android App.

Following the Spotify Tutorial it says to download Spotify Android playback library zip and Spotify Android auth library zip from GitHub and unzip them.

Next it says to copy the spotify-auth-version.aar and spotify-player-version.aar files into the /app/libs directory in your project’s root directory.

After unzipping the two downloads I can find the spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b.aar but I am unable to find the Spotify-auth-version.aar file.

I read the Readme that came with the Android auth library zip and it says Run `./gradlew build` and grab an artifact from `auth-lib/build/outputs/aar/`.

My question is how do I do this?  Is this done via the cmd prompt?  Or do I have to open the project in Android studio?  When I tried opening the project it just came up blank.

I know I need to build the project to get the aar file, I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have you read this **[tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/)**? Take a look at the **Installing the Android SDK** section.

Comment: Yes that is the tutorial which I'm following.  It gives the impression that the two aar files should be there but the Spotify-auth-version.aar is not

Comment: Actually, I don't think you should need the **spotify-player-version.aar** file, in fact, they don't use it in their **SDK [DemoProject](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/tree/master/samples/DemoProject)**. Just try to add this line `compile 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.0.0-alpha'` into your **build.gradle** and sync it.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean sync it?

Comment: Go to: Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Is this in my project or the android-auth-1.0 project?  As I am not able to open the android-auth-1.0 project in android studio

Comment: Yes, in your project, you don't need the android-auth-1.0 project.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this take it straight from the web then?

Comment: Exactly. You've got it.

Comment: Much appreciated